# Why python code accepts '.' and '-' as numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Use case:
ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits.

If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return true, else return false.

My code is working for all the randomly generated pins except for:

'12.0'
'1234.0'
'111-'
'44444-'

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    numbers = '0123456789'
    if len(pin) != 4 and len(pin) != 6:
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(len(pin)):
            if pin[i] in numbers:
                return True
            else:
                break
        return False
```

Any idea why this would be? These characters do not live within my created variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [kaya3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299000/kaya3) suggested, the best way to solve issues like this is to step through with a debugger. You can do this in VS code by hitting "Run and Debug" on the debug tab shown below:

[image]

Basically your code is checking if the *first* character is in numbers or not. If it is a number, the for loop breaks, if it isn't, the for loop breaks. Here's a small fix:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
numbers = '0123456789'
if len(pin) != 4 and len(pin) != 6:
    return False
else:
    for i in range(len(pin)):
        if pin[i] not in numbers:
            return False
        # if pin[i] in numbers:
        #     return True
        # else:
        #     break
    return True
```

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing on these examples because it is only checking if the length is correct and if the first digit is a number.

This section of your code is where the issue is:

```py
else:
        for i in range(len(pin)):
            if pin[i] in numbers:
                return True
```

In all of your test cases, `i` will initially be `0`.  It will check if `pin[0]` is in the set of numbers and return `True`.  The `return` statement breaks you out of the loop and doesn't check `pin[1]`, `pin[2]`, etc.  You need to change your code to check all digits.